# How to change the state inside a Component once my Context is changed

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display Like-Buttons of liked Posts in a different Color. To accomplish this i make my Component Check if the post is liked by the User that is saved in the State Context like so:

```
const { credentials, isLoggedIn } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { username } = credentials;

  const checkLiked = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < likes.length; i++) {
      if (likes[i].username === username) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };

  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(checkLiked());
```

I render my like Icon with conditional styling like this:

```
 <PublishIcon
        name='upvote'
        onClick={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          username !== null ? upvotePost() : setShowRegister();
        }}
        className={styles.icon}
        style={{ color: isLiked ? (isLoggedIn ? "#f50057" : "") : "" }}
        fontSize='large'
      />
```

now I need to find a way to when the User logs in trigger the checkForLiked function again so that I can display already liked Post in the Corresponding color.

Is there any react feature that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```
const { credentials: { username } } = useContext(UserContext);

useEffect(()=>{
 checkLiked();
},[username]//fires when username is set or changes
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really messing with me haha...